# Office 365 MS Access Enable Macros in the Registry

Tags: ms-access, office365, registry

Can you enable macros for Access through the registry? If so, what is the path?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following registry hive:

```
software\policies\microsoft\office\16.0\outlook\security
```

where 16.0 should correspond to the host application version.

See [Security setting for macros](https://admx.help/?Category=Office2016&Policy=outlk16.Office.Microsoft.Policies.Windows::L_SecurityLevelOutlook) for more information about possible values.